# How to list struct information in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I can check non-struct types,but when checking struct,always getting a "`Function "struct" not defined.`":

```
(gdb) l ngx_http_request_t
10  
11  #include <ngx_config.h>
12  #include <ngx_core.h>
13  
14  
15  typedef struct ngx_http_request_s     ngx_http_request_t;
16  typedef struct ngx_http_upstream_s    ngx_http_upstream_t;
17  typedef struct ngx_http_cache_s       ngx_http_cache_t;
18  typedef struct ngx_http_file_cache_s  ngx_http_file_cache_t;
19  typedef struct ngx_http_log_ctx_s     ngx_http_log_ctx_t;
(gdb) l struct ngx_http_request_s
Function "struct" not defined.
```

Is it possible in gdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ptype ngx_http_request_t`

Comment: For lldb, the command is `im loo -t ngx_http_request_t` (for lldb users who google for gdb instead)

Answer (score 2):

`l` is usually used with a line number to view a particular line of code, although it can be used with a function name.
Because `struct` is not a line number or a function name, you can not view its definition.
What type of output are you expecting?
It looks like you really want the values of the data in the `struct`, meaning you have to create a struct of that type first.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value of the variable declared with that type:

```
ngx_http_request_t foo;
```

(gdb) print foo

Comment: what if I can't find a variable declared with that type?

Comment: yakatz is right. You need a variable of that type to examine it.